My code has a 'Type parameter cannot be instantiated directly' error. How do i solve it?
Type parameter 'UserModel' cannot be instantiated directly
userModel = new UserModel (id, email, password, new Constants().equals("students"));
I tried:
public class Register<UserModel> extends AppCompatActivity { TextInputEditText edEmail, edPassword, edConfirmPassword; private UserModel userModel; 
